# range slider with angularjs and step

Tags: angularjs

So, I am using the range slider in an angularJS application.
It looks like this:

```
<input type="range" step="3" min="3" max="9" ng-model="question.score" ng-change="controller.arrangeQuestions()" integer />
```

The problem is my client has asked me to adjust the scoring.
He wants the **min** to be 1, the **max** to be 9, but only wants one other option with a score of 2.
How can I set this up?

Comment: can you please explain "wants one other option" ?

Comment: if I understood well: expected values of the slider are: 1,2,3,6,9. right?

Comment: so basically 1,2 and 9 with only 3 steps. My current solution is to take the values and do a swtich statement returning 1 for 3, 2 for 6 and default return 9

Comment: Do you must use HTML5 slider, or can use jQuery slider ?

Comment: I don't mix angular with jquery